# Passing Variable into Callback PHP

Tags: php, callback

I have a function below that is called and passed an array. I would also like to pass it a field (or key) name so that it is reusable. When I try to pass $field in the callback as below I get an error that $field is not defined. If I use a literal, it works great.

```
function array_map_recursive($array,$field) {
        $sum = 0;
        foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
           foreach ($value as $key2 => $value2) {
               $sum += array_sum(array_map(function($item){return $item[$field];},$value[$key2]));
           }
        }
        return $sum;
}
```

called:

```
number_format(array_map_recursive($dept_catg_grp_descs,"total_ty_yest_sales"))
```

Comment: You have to use `use` construct (http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)

Comment: Thanks, learned something new!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
function ($item) use ($field) {return $item[$field];}
```

This "imports" the `$field` variable into the function.

Answer (score 0):

Simple: You need to declare which variables from the outer scope you want to use in your closure, such as:

```
function array_map_recursive($array,$field) {
    $sum = 0;
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
       foreach ($value as $key2 => $value2) {
           $sum += array_sum(array_map(function($item) use($field) {return $item[$field];},$value[$key2]));
       }
    }
    return $sum;
}
```

Note the *use* clause.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass your parameter with 'use'